# Can these unit tests be improved?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing

I'm not the greatest at writing tests yet and I'm starting a new OSS project for learning and as part of it I want to tackle being more effective at writing tests, more specifically quality tests. I think I write a lot of tests that don't bring much value except maintenance pain sometimes.

Can I improve these tests?

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using FakeItEasy;
using HaywireMQ.Server.Channel;
using HaywireMQ.Server.MessageStore;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using Ploeh.AutoFixture;
using Ploeh.AutoFixture.AutoFakeItEasy;

namespace HaywireMQ.Server.Tests
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Tests for HaywireServer
    /// </summary>
    [TestClass]
    public class HaywireServerTests
    {
        private IFixture fixture;

        public HaywireServerTests()
        {
        }

        [TestInitialize]
        public void Initialize()
        {
            fixture = new Fixture().Customize(new AutoFakeItEasyCustomization());
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void Should_use_defaults_without_ModuleCatalog()
        {
            // Given
            var target = new HaywireServer();

            // When
            target.Start();

            // Then
            Assert.AreEqual<Type>(target.MessageStore.GetType(), typeof(InMemoryMessageStore));
            Assert.AreEqual<Type>(target.MessageChannel.GetType(), typeof(InMemoryMessageChannel));
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void Should_use_ModuleCatalog()
        {
            // Given
            var catalog = new ModuleCatalog();
            var messageStore = fixture.CreateAnonymous<IMessageStore>();
            var messageChannel = fixture.CreateAnonymous<IMessageChannel>();
            catalog.MessageStores.Add(messageStore);
            catalog.MessageChannels.Add(messageChannel);
            var target = new HaywireServer(catalog);

            // When
            target.Start();

            // Then
            Assert.AreEqual<Type>(target.MessageStore.GetType(), messageStore.GetType());
            Assert.AreEqual<Type>(target.MessageChannel.GetType(), messageChannel.GetType());
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void Should_create_MessageQueue()
        {
            // Given
            var catalog = new ModuleCatalog();
            var messageStore = fixture.CreateAnonymous<IMessageStore>();
            var messageChannel = fixture.CreateAnonymous<IMessageChannel>();
            catalog.MessageStores.Add(messageStore);
            catalog.MessageChannels.Add(messageChannel);
            var target = new HaywireServer(catalog);

            List<string> ids = new List<string>() {"test"};

            A.CallTo(() => messageStore.GetQueues()).Returns(ids);

            // When
            target.Start();

            // Then
            A.CallTo(() => messageStore.GetQueues()).MustHaveHappened();
            Assert.AreEqual<int>(target.MessageQueues.Count, 1);
            Assert.AreEqual<string>(target.MessageQueues[0].Id, "test");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: One improvement is to use xUnit.net instead of MSTest which integrates with AutoFixture and allows you to parameterize those tests via data theories. Once you have parameterized tests, AutoFixture can take care of the rest supplying the parameter values for you and even Auto-Mock them using FakeItEasy. :)

Comment: I would not use MSTest. It's slower than the alternatives and has fewer features.

Comment: You're probably better at testing than me, but shouldn't there really only be one Assert per test method?

Comment: Each test should test only one "thing". So having a couple of Asserts in a test is actually fine. For example, it_should_return_empty_string() would be perfectly fine to have Assert.IsNotNull(result) and Assert.Equals(String.Empty, result).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming that I've correctly managed to extrapolate the [SUT](http://xunitpatterns.com/SUT.html) and friends from the question, I'd reduce the tests to the following. Please note that this focuses only on [AutoFixture](http://autofixture.codeplex.com/) mechanics, and not on the general design of neither test nor SUT API.

AFAICT, the following tests state the same as the tests in the OP, but reduced to only the necessary statements. Still, I agree with Nikos Baxevanis that it would be possible to reduce these tests dramatically with [xUnit.net](http://xunit.codeplex.com/) instead of MSTest.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using FakeItEasy;
using FirstAutoFixtureReviewForKellySommers;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using Ploeh.AutoFixture;
using Ploeh.AutoFixture.AutoFakeItEasy;
using Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel;

namespace HaywireMQ.Server.Tests
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Tests for HaywireServer
    /// </summary>
    [TestClass]
    public class HaywireServerTests
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void Should_use_defaults_without_ModuleCatalog()
        {
            // Given
            var fixture = new Fixture().Customize(new TestConventions());

            // When
            var target = fixture.CreateAnonymous<HaywireServer>();

            // Then
            Assert.IsInstanceOfType(target.MessageStore, typeof(InMemoryMessageStore));
            Assert.IsInstanceOfType(target.MessageChannel, typeof(InMemoryMessageChannel));
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void Should_use_ModuleCatalog()
        {
            // Given
            var fixture = new Fixture().Customize(new TestConventions());

            var catalog = fixture.Freeze<ModuleCatalog>();
            fixture.AddManyTo(catalog.MessageStores, 1);
            fixture.AddManyTo(catalog.MessageChannels, 1);

            // When
            var target = fixture.CreateAnonymous<HaywireServer>();

            // Then
            Assert.AreEqual(catalog.MessageStores.Single(), target.MessageStore);
            Assert.AreEqual(catalog.MessageChannels.Single(), target.MessageChannel);
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void Should_create_MessageQueue()
        {
            // Given
            var fixture = new Fixture().Customize(new TestConventions());

            var catalog = fixture.Freeze<ModuleCatalog>();
            fixture.AddManyTo(catalog.MessageStores, 1);

            List<string> ids = fixture.CreateMany<string>(1).ToList();
            A.CallTo(() => catalog.MessageStores.Single().GetQueues()).Returns(ids);

            var target = fixture.CreateAnonymous<HaywireServer>();

            // When
            target.Start();

            // Then
            A.CallTo(() => catalog.MessageStores.Single().GetQueues()).MustHaveHappened();
            Assert.AreEqual(1, target.MessageQueues.Count);
            Assert.AreEqual(ids.First(), target.MessageQueues[0].Id);
        }

        private class TestConventions : CompositeCustomization
        {
            public TestConventions()
                : base(
                    new AutoFakeItEasyCustomization(),
                    new GreedyHaywireServerCustomization())
            {
            }
        }

        private class GreedyHaywireServerCustomization : ICustomization
        {
            public void Customize(IFixture fixture)
            {
                fixture.Customize<HaywireServer>(c =>
                    c.FromFactory(new MethodInvoker(new GreedyConstructorQuery())));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Curious why you removed the `TestInitialize` method in favor of setting up the fixture in each test? I'm generally also of the opinion that too much DRY-aware refactoring makes tests less expressive, but would have thought that something like this that is purely infrastructural is a good candidate for moving out of the way of the actual meat of the test case (particularly since you aren't really increasing the information locality, since the important part is in TestConventions anyways).

Comment: I have an (irrational or subjective) dislike of Implicit Setup because I feel that the lack of proximity between a [TestInitialize] method and the last test cases in a (larger) test file makes it too hard to understand what's going on at a glance. I prefer each test case to be self-contained.

Comment: @MarkSeemann I find that harder to read because there's more AutoFixture than what I'd call regular use of the code involved. To someone new to using AutoFixture I'm not sure what Freeze() or GreedyConstructorQuery does.

What does CreateAnonymous() do? I thought it created the fake but now it looks to be the concrete type.

SUT was meant to be what I named "target" just to clarify.

Also was adding to the catalog left out on purpose? Reason I ask is in Start() exceptions occur if no MessageChannel or MessageStore is detected in the catalog.

These questions probably due to misunderstanding :)

Comment: AutoFixture is a DSL. Tests will be harder to read until you understand the language - as with all other DSLs.

Comment: CreateAnonymous creates the type you ask for. If you ask for a concrete type, you get back a concrete type. If you ask for an interface, you get back a fake, courtesy of the FakeItEasy customization.

Comment: I left out adding to the catalog because it seemed to add no value. Remember that I've never seen the SUT - I extrapolated from your tests. Nothing in these tests indicated that Start might throw exceptions if no MessageChannel or MessageStore was detected. If that's the case, there should be a test case stating exactly that, and nothing else.

Comment: @MarkSeemann Just to make sure I understand correctly. I should put the catalog back in those tests since it's required for Start() and  then write a new test that tests for the exception case? What does Freeze() do?

Comment: Yes, or better yet: improve the design in order to get rid of the Temporal Coupling.

Comment: Freeze: http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/03/17/AutoFixtureFreeze.aspx

Answer (score 6):

I think it's quite well written, would have only two ideas.

1. For the repeating part of the fixture setup (given) I'd consider using a [Standard Fixture](http://xunitpatterns.com/Standard%20Fixture.html), probably via a setup helper method.
2. I'd consider splitting the [state and behaviour verification](http://xunitpatterns.com/Result%20Verification%20Patterns.html) parts of `Should_create_MessageQueue()` into two separate test methods. The behaviour verification of `MustHaveHappened()` deals with a different issue than the state verification with the asserts.

Answer (score 3):

A couple of points that I can see:

In Should_use_ModuleCatalog,

- I see that the test is around the HaywireServer since the assert
  is after the action on target. However, the asserts are on properties
  of ModuleCatalog. I would prefer this test to be a catalog's test
  rather than a target's test.
- What does this testcase ensure? It
  tells me that the properties are set with the appropriate types. I
  wouldn't test this out explicitly unless there are branching
  workflows that could set different types based on context.
- Catalog seems to have a List of MessageStore, however when catalog is
  injected into the target, the target seems to have just one
  MessageStore - Is there a logic around this? If so I would test that
  out.

Something that I noted (not related to the testing aspect):
this line:

```
catalog.MessageStores.Add(messageStore);
```

tells me that Catalog has a List (or a similar collection) - which isn't necessarily something to be published as a contract to consumers.
I would prefer something like:

```
catalog.AddMessageStore(messageStore)
```

so that I am free to refactor ModuleCatalog to use any internal mechanism of holding this.